# Can I establish a video call programmatically using UCMA 3.0?

Tags: video, lync, lync-2010, ucma, video-conferencing

Is it doable using UCMA 3.0, to have video conferencing ?

Answer (score 1):

What scenario do you have in mind?

UCMA is normally used as a server-based API, so it's not usual for a UCMA application to initiate or receive video calls (as there's no one at the application!), though I see no particular reason why this can't be done. I've not done it but I guess it would be do-able to create a UCMA application which, when you call it, connects to a video device - a sort of CCTV contact! If this is what you're interested in doing let me know and I'll see if I can put a code sample together.

However, you can also perform a back-to-back transfer, where an incoming video call (incoming to the UCMA application) is handed off to another user, whilst still giving the impression that it's been answered by the application. MSDN has a [good four-part series](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh527740) on B2B.

You can also use UCMA to set up, invite, and manage video conferencing sessions between users, if that's more what you're interested in.